# Can I use my GPU to share some computing tasks?

Tags: gpu

I'm writting a opengl C program, and I know that most graphical jobs are done by the GPU. My question is, can I use the GPU to compute stuff that is not graphic-related? For example, compute `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 100 = ?`

Comment: Answer: yes of course. CUDA, anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can by using OpenCL or Computeshaders (thats the DX name, but I think theres something similar in openGl). But in general it only makes sense for algorithms that are easy to parallelize and way bigger than your example.

Comment: Thanks. I Googled and as the others have said, CUDA is indeed another choice.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for General Purpose GPU computing (GPGPU).

Check out [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) and
[OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an Expert on GPUs but as far as I know YES. Since the GPU is optimized for the graphic operations I don't know about the performance and scalability.

Check this [article](http://joubert.posterous.com/adding-two-arbitrary-precision-integers-using).

Answer (score 1):

Your question **if it can do 1 + 2 + 3 + .... + 100 = .. ?**

Answer: **Yes**

This might raise another question: **What is the advantage of using GPU hardware for Computation?**
Answer: It can execute hundreds of such '1+2+3+..+100==..','101+102+...+200=..', '201+202+...+300=..' operations in parallel way!

With its enhanced hardware a GPU is capable of performing computations in parallel way, within fractions of seconds. GPU has hundreds of cores and they can be utilized for the non-graphics functions also. Advantage of this many core architecture can be taken to perform many scientific computations and simulation. Read the concept of General Purpose Graphics Programming Unit. [GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units)